# How can I read binary file in java which is written in c#

Tags: java, binaryfiles

I have to read binary file which is written in c#. And I know this file format. I want to learn if is it possible.  And how can I do it if it is possible.

Comment: `FileInputStream` reads the file byte by byte.

Comment: If you want a specific answer, you'll need to modify the question so that it is less ambiguous. Did your C# program serialize objects to a binary format? If so, it could be hard to read that into Java objects. But if your C# code generated language-independent binary data, then it is a trivial matter to read the data again, in (almost) any language.

Comment: I had a need for this and wrote an equivalent class.

https://gist.github.com/vangorra/9470810

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very ambiguous, but I'll assume you're asking "how do I read a binary file?" In that case, the answer is to use a `FileInputStream` to read all the bytes. If you know the filepath, then you can use the code below to read all the bytes from a file:

```
byte[] readBytes(string filepath)
{
    File file = new File(filepath);
    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
    // create buffer of the correct size
    byte[] buffer = new byte[file.length()];
    // read in the data
    stream.read(buffer);
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: @zeitgeist Is that what you're asking?...